# How to get Payment done by Credit Card Transaction (done not by PayPal account ) in my PayPal Sandbox account.

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, payflowpro, website-payment-pro

I want to have  payment done by  Credit Card Transaction (done not by PayPal account ) in my PayPal Sandbox account as test credit card transaction.

I failed in doing so.

(Till now I have tried:

1. I have created "Buy Now" through Website Payment Pro. For Payment
   I have selected "Don't have a PayPal account?". Entered test credit card no. and real email address of my gmail account.
   I am getting error  "You cannot use an e-mail address or card number that belongs
   to an existing PayPal account. If you have a PayPal account, please log in.
   If you don't, please change the e-mail address or card number and try again."
2. Tried Payflow Pro also but couldnt find out  how to do any Payflow Pro Payment which I can see in my PayPal Sandbox account as a credit card payment.

Please help me. I am stuck on this from so many days

Thanks in advance.

:Jyoti